# Added jquery datepicker and its css affects other parts of the page

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 6 to make an ajax powered site.  The index page uses off canvas and tabs for navigation.  But when I added the jquery datepicker widget and the corresponding css, it is adversely affecting the appearance of my navigation bar.

I make no reference to the ui classes in my navigation source code, but foundation or something is putting them into the served version.

for example:

source code snippet:

```html
    <li>
        <a id="select-sections" href="#tabs-2" class="hollow button secondary disabled" data-open="offCanvasLeft">
            §§
        </a>
    </li>
```

but firebug shows:

```html
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="select-sections" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
        <a id="select-sections" class="hollow button secondary disabled ui-tabs-anchor" href="#tabs-2" data-open="offCanvasLeft" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="offCanvasLeft"> §§ </a>
    </li>
```

Obviously, when I add the CSS for datepicker widget, It's using css styles that I never intended to use on my menus.  I really don't want it to add stuff like "ui-state-default" and "ui-corner-top" to my code.

Two possible ways I can see to potentially solve the problem, just don't know how to accomplish it:

1. Somehow prevent the addition of ui-* classes to my navigation
2. Somehow make the css apply only to the datepicker

If it helps, here is a simplified listing

```html
<body>
    <div class="full-height">
        <div id="topbar" class="top-bar">
          <div class="top-bar-title"> The site title... </div>
          <div>
            <div id="top-bar-left-content" class="top-bar-left"></div>
            <div id-"top-bar-right-content" class="top-bar-right">                
                <form>
                    <ul class="logged_in menu">
                        <li>Date:&nbsp; </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="today" value="<%= @today %>"></li>
                        <li><input class="button primary" type="submit" value="Change Date"></li>
                        <li><button id="select-help" class="button primary">Help</button></li>
                    </ul>        
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    <span id="notice"><%= notice %></span>

    <!-- wrap entire document (2 divs) -->
    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper container"><div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner fill" data-off-canvas-wrapper>

    <!-- tabs wrap around off-canvas and off-canvas data.  using .tabs class distorts display. -->
    <div id="tabs" class="fill ">


      <!-- off canvas left (hidden) part -->
      <div id="offCanvasLeft" class="off-canvas position-left fill" data-off-canvas data-close-on-click=false>

        <!-- tabs content -->
        <aside>
            <div id="tabs-1">A list of links...</div>
            <div id="tabs-2">A list of links...</div>
            <div id="tabs-3">A list of links...</div>
            <div id="tabs-4">A list of links...</div>
            <div id="tabs-5">A list of links...</div>
        </aside>  

      </div><!-- end off canvas left -->


      <!-- rest of the page (on canvas) -->
      <div id="left-scroll" class="off-canvas-content rows fill" data-off-canvas-content>

        <!-- sidebar icons. these select the tab to display -->
        <ul id="sidebar-closed" class="menu vertical sidebar-closed">
            <!-- toggle sidebar -->
            <li id="toggle-oc">
                <a class="hollow button secondary" data-toggle="offCanvasLeft">
                    <i id="toggle-menu" class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- search -->
            <li>
                <a id="select-search" href="#tabs-3" class="hollow button secondary is-active" data-open="offCanvasLeft">
                    <i class=" fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- part list -->
            <li>
                <a id="select-parts" href="#tabs-1" class="hollow button secondary" data-open="offCanvasLeft">
                    <i class=" fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- section list -->
            <li>
                <a id="select-sections" href="#tabs-2" class="hollow button secondary disabled" data-open="offCanvasLeft">
                    §§
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- letter list -->
            <li>
                <a id="select-letters-list" href="#tabs-4" class="hollow button secondary disabled" data-open="offCanvasLeft"><!--  data-pushstate="/sidebar_actions/letters" -->
                    <i class=" fa fa-files-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <!-- main window content -->

        <main>
            links in the tabs are displayed here

        </main>


        </div><!--  rest of page (on canvas) wrapper -->
    </div> <!-- tabs wrapper -->
    </div></div> <!-- outer 2 off-canvas wrappers -->
</body>
```

and the css is loaded via application.css.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require font-awesome

 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the css apply only to the datepicker widget. For Ror:

1. Use firebug to determine the `id` of the wrapping div.
2. Use [jQuery Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) to generate the CSS you need.  Add `id` from step 1 to the `CSS Scope` input.
3. Remove `*= require jquery-ui/datepicker` from application.css.scss
4. Make new file in app/assets/stylesheets and paste generated stylesheet
5. Change any references to `url(images/*` to `url(/images/*`
6. Copy required images to public/images/